# Why are "joke" questions tolerated?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand why [this question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/829/why-is-there-a-health-channel-people-never-answer-questions-here) wasn't deleted outright to begin with since the OP readily admitted it wasn't a real question. It got moved to meta, where the OP is now using it as a vehicle to continue his mockery.

Why? What makes this question worth preserving in any way?

Comment: It was moved to meta from main, as it was originally just posted with no comments. That is when the retag occurred. I had not seen the comments on it after, although I read it as the mental health tag was a joke, not the entire question.

Comment: Why can't it just be deleted entirely?

Comment: I'll restate this question @JohnP - why can't it be deleted entirely?  As it is locked, it has a 0 rating and that makes it appear that it wasn't downvoted - so even though it's closed it looks like it's legit.  The guy even admitted it was a troll post, does it have to clutter up our page?